# Compare Values of 2 dataframes conditionally

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have the following problem. I have a dataframe which look like this.

Dataframe1

```
   start  end
0      0    2
1      3    7
2      8    9
```

and another dataframe which looks like this.

Dataframe2

```
   data
1   ...
4   ...
8   ...
11  ...
```

What I am trying to achieve is following:

For each row in Dataframe1 I want to check if there is any index value in Dataframe2 which is in range(start, end) of Dataframe1.
If the condition is True, I want to create a new column["condition"] where the outcome is stored.

Since there is the possiblity to deal with large amounts of data I tried using numpy.select.

Like this:

```
range_start = df1.start
range_end = df1.end

condition = [
    df2.index.to_series().between(range_start, range_end)
]

choice = ["True"]

df1["condition"] = np.select(condition, choice, default=0)
```

This gives me an error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I also tried a list comprehension. That didn't work either. All the things I tried are failing because I am dealing with a series (--> range_start, range_end). There has to be a way to make this work I think..

I already searched stackoverflow for this paricular problem. But I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem. It could be, that I'm just to inexperienced for this type of problem, to search for the right solution.

So maybe you can help me out here.

Thank you!

expected output:

```
   start  end  condition
0      0    2       True
1      3    7       True
2      8    9       True
```

Comment: Kindly provide expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for remove duplicates by both columns and index, create all combinations by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with cross join and last test at least one match by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df3 = (df1.drop_duplicates(['start','end'])
          .merge(df2.index.drop_duplicates().to_frame(), how='cross'))

df3['condition'] = df3[0].between(df3.start, df3.end)

df3 = df1.join(df3.groupby(['start','end'])['condition'].any(), on=['start','end'])
print (df3)
   start  end  condition
0      0    2       True
1      3    7       True
2      8    9       True
```

If all pairs in `df1` are unique is possible use:

```
df3 = (df1.merge(df2.index.to_frame(), how='cross'))

df3['condition'] = df3[0].between(df3.start, df3.end)

df3 = df3.groupby(['start','end'], as_index=False)['condition'].any()
print (df3)
   start  end  condition
0      0    2       True
1      3    7       True
2      8    9       True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted the "condition" column in df1 and not df2. When trying --> `df1["condition"] = i.get_indexer(df2.index) != -1` I get the error `ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (3)`

Comment: @som3k - answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222905/pandas-count-the-number-of-occurrence-of-all-matched-patterns-in-a-column