# Pandas : Count the number of occurrence of all matched patterns in a column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, group-by

Say I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['ABC DEF', 'JKL', 'GHI  ABC', 'ABC ABC', 'DEF GHI', 'DEF', 'DEF DEF', 'ABC GHI DEF ABC'],
    'column_2': [9, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 1 ]
})
```

```
df
          column_1  column_2
0          ABC DEF         9
1         GHI  ABC         3
2          ABC ABC         4
3          DEF GHI         6
4              DEF         2
5          DEF DEF         7
6  ABC GHI DEF ABC         1
```

I want to count the number of times each of my regex pattern group is present in the column.

For simplicity, say the pattern is the word `ABC and DEF` then I need the count of those in all the rows.

Expected output :

```
          column_1  column_2    Group1_count   Group2_count
0          ABC DEF         9         1              1
1              JKL         9         0              0
2         GHI  ABC         3         1              0
3          ABC ABC         4         2              0
4          DEF GHI         6         0              1
5              DEF         2         0              1
6          DEF DEF         7         0              2
7  ABC GHI DEF ABC         1         2              1
```

This is what I tried, where I am unable to figure out how to move ahead to get the count value.

```
df['column_1'].str.extractall('(ABC)|(DEF)').groupby(level=0).first()

      0     1
0   ABC   DEF
2   ABC  None
3   ABC  None
4  None   DEF
5  None   DEF
6  None   DEF
7   ABC   DEF
```

A vector solution/one liner approach would be appreciated for this question.
Also note that in this example I have `ABC` and `DEF` for simplicity but it could be a complex regex pattern as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': ['ABC DEF', 'GHI  ABC', 'ABC ABC', 'DEF GHI', 'XYZ', 'DEF DEF', 'ABC GHI DEF ABC'],
                   'column_2': [9, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 1]})
df = df.merge(df['column_1'].str.extractall('(ABC)|(DEF)').groupby(level=0).count(), how='outer', left_index=True,
              right_index=True).fillna(0).rename(columns={0: "Group1_count", 1: "Group2_count"}).astype(
    {"Group1_count": 'int32', "Group2_count": 'int32'})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          column_1  column_2  Group1_count  Group2_count
0          ABC DEF         9             1             1
1         GHI  ABC         3             1             0
2          ABC ABC         4             2             0
3          DEF GHI         6             0             1
4              XYZ         2             0             0
5          DEF DEF         7             0             2
6  ABC GHI DEF ABC         1             2             1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired result with your approach if you sum the `notna` instead of `first`, and then join back with the original `df`

```py
df.join(df['column_1'].str.extractall('(ABC)|(DEF)').notna().groupby(level=0).sum(), how='left').fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
          column_1  column_2    0    1
0          ABC DEF         9  1.0  1.0
1              JKL         2  0.0  0.0
2         GHI  ABC         3  1.0  0.0
3          ABC ABC         4  2.0  0.0
4          DEF GHI         6  0.0  1.0
5              DEF         2  0.0  1.0
6          DEF DEF         7  0.0  2.0
7  ABC GHI DEF ABC         1  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: this does not work if I have no matched value in the dataframe, say a row containing `XYZ`. I have updated the dataframe please check

Answer (score 2):

Check Below, continuation of your code. You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with `count` which computes count of each column, excluding missing values(NaN, None).

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['ABC DEF', 'GHI  ABC', 'ABC ABC', 'DEF GHI', 'DEF', 'DEF DEF', 'ABC GHI DEF ABC'],
    'column_2': [9, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 1 ]
})

df['column_1'].str.extractall('(ABC)|(DEF)').groupby(level=0).agg('count')
```

Output:

[image]

Updated:

```
df['column_1'].str.extractall('(ABC)|(DEF)|''').groupby(level=0).agg('count')
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, the trick is in `(ABC)|(DEF)|''` can you explain it

Comment: Essentially placeholder in case no option is available